# How to see what site template is used in SharePoint Online (Office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-template

Is there a simple way for me to see what template was used for a site collection in SharePoint Online (Office 365)?

The Site Collection properties only show details like "number of subsites", "title", ... but not the template used.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On your site, view the source of the start page (ctrl + U) and search for JavaScript variable `g_wsaSiteTemplateId`.

You'll get the Template ID like this

```
var g_wsaSiteTemplateId = 'STS#0';
```

Then just find what template that is in the list presented in the article [SharePoint 2013 Site Template ID](http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/06/sharepoint-2013-site-template-id-list-for-powershell.html)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Benny. Got the confirmation I needed that the Team Site Templates were used (STS#0)

Answer (score 6):

I've been trying to find out why when I search the Source Code from my 365 tennant I can't find a 'g_wsaSiteTemplateID' variable anywhere. It seems like the variable name has been changed to 'webTemplateConfiguration'.

I found my Template ID looking like this:

```
"webTemplateConfiguration":"STS#0",
```

The values don't seem to have changed though so you can still correlate what you find with mentioned [article](http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/06/sharepoint-2013-site-template-id-list-for-powershell.html).

Comment: In a classic publishing subsite which I thought was created as a modern team site I get "webTemplateConfiguration":"STS#3". ST#3 doesn't appear in the template list.

Comment: Found it here: https://www.technologytobusiness.com/microsoft-sharepoint/sharepoint-online-site-template-id